# Duplicate records when running a DAO recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, recordset

I developed an access database  to log jobs throughout a production process. Every record has an order, machine, start time, end time among other characteristics of the job. When an order is logged, it is saved in the database along with the machine name, start time and job status (running or idle). When the order is completed, the record is searched using a recordset and "end time" is saved. If the machine is not being utilized, like between shifts, the machine should have an "idle" status.

The purpose of OpenRecMassUpdate is to add an 'end time' to all the incomplete records (those with an order, start time but without end time). This code is used at the end of shift so that all the records could be closed with one click.

After executing this subroutine, the machines that were assigned to an order are now without a status. As a result, I needed another subroutine to add "idle" statuses to all these machines. That is the purpose of MassIdleUpdate. It creates an idle record for every machine that was previously used and status closed using OpenRecMassUpdate.

The problem I am facing is that MassIdleUpdate creates multiple records at random times. When I run analysis on the database, I found some records that were created 3, 4 or more times.

```
Option Compare Database

Dim dbsn As DAO.Database
Dim rstn As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQLqueryn As String
Dim recordcount As Integer
Dim tempstat As String
Dim stat1 As Integer

Public Sub OpenRecMassUpdate()

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  recordcount = 1
  tempstat = "Idle"
  stat1 = 0
  Set dbsn = CurrentDb

  SQLqueryn = "SELECT * FROM kettleLog WHERE KettleStatus <> """ & tempstat & _
              """ And KettleLogic = " & stat1

  Set rstn = dbsn.OpenRecordset(SQLqueryn)
  With rstn
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
      .MoveLast
      .MoveFirst
      While (Not .EOF)
        .Edit
        .Fields("KettleFinish") = Now()
        .Fields("KettleLogic") = -1
        .Fields("EndOfShift") = 1
        .Update
        .MoveNext
        recordcount = recordcount + 1
      Wend
      MsgBox recordcount - 1 & " records were updated as a result of the end of the shift"
      recordcount = 1
    Else
    End If
    .Close
  End With

  dbsn.Close

ExitSub:
  Set dbsn = Nothing
  Set rstn = Nothing
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
  Resume ExitSub

End Sub

Public Sub MassIdleUpdate()

  Dim tempKettle As String

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Set dbsn = CurrentDb

  SQLqueryn = "SELECT * FROM kettleLog WHERE EndOfShift = 1"

  Set rstn = dbsn.OpenRecordset(SQLqueryn)
  With rstn
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
      .MoveLast
      .MoveFirst
      For i = 1 To FindRecordCount(SQLqueryn)
        tempKettle = .Fields("Kettle")
        .Edit
        .Fields("EndOfShift") = 3
        .Update
        .AddNew
        .Fields("Kettle") = tempKettle
        .Fields("KettleStatus") = "Idle"
        .Fields("WorkOrder") = 0
        .Fields("KettleStart") = Now()
        .Fields("KettleLogic") = 0
        .Fields("EndOfShift") = 2
        .Update
        .MoveNext
      Next
    End If
    .Close
  End With

  tempKetlle = ""
  dbsn.Close
  i = 1

ExitSub:
  Set dbsn = Nothing
  Set rstn = Nothing

  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
  Resume ExitSub

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `.MoveLast` and then `.MoveFirst` if you're not going to be using `.RecordCount` anyway?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I read it was a good practice prior to any operation with recordsets.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I asked my question in a different way. In addition to that, I added more details as to what's going on with this subroutine.

Comment: You need to debug a single run of `MassIdleUpdate` and analyze the results.  That code is never looping through all of the records where `EndOfShift=1` because your loop is dynamically getting shorter with each iteration.  My guess is that users are clicking your button multiple times trying to get the desired results. Please post details about the state of the records after ONE run of that code (i.e. started with 30 records, only 15 got updated to `3`, etc). Also post details about what `FindRecordCount` is doing. If it is doing as the name suggests, that is one of your problems.

Comment: In `Sub OpenRecMassUpdate()` you have an `Else` with nothing in it. Is there supposed to be something there? If not, you can remove it - all it's doing is causing questions.

Comment: Additionally, it may be easier to simply do a single `UPDATE` statement like this: `UPDATE KettleLog SET KettleFinish = Now(), KettleLogic = -1, EndOfShift = 1 WHERE KettleStatus <> "Idle" AND KettleLogic = 0`. Note: I hard coded the `WHERE` conditions for brevity I like your method a bit better, though it's not necessary. Also, if you need to know how many records were updated, set a variable = `Now()`, pass that in, then do a separate `COUNT()` where `KettleFinish = thatTime` to get the record count. No need to loop through all those records 1 by 1

Comment: @FreeMan the reason of the Else was to show a message that no record has been found open. I decided to omitted to reduce the number of pop up windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping through all your records counting them and setting the values individually, do it all in one shot. An RDBMS (even Access) is designed for this kind of bulk update.

```
Public Sub OpenRecMassUpdate()

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim tempStat As String
  tempStat = "Idle"
  Dim stat1 As Long
  stat1 = 0
  Set dbsn = CurrentDb

  Dim timeStamp As Date
  timeStamp = Now()
  SQLqueryn = "UPDATE KettleLog " & _
              "   SET KettleFinish = #" & timeStamp & "#, " & _
              "       KettleLogic = -1, " & _
              "       EndOfShift = 1 " & _
              " WHERE KettleStatus <> """ & tempStat & """" & _
              "   AND KettleLogic = 0"

  Set rstn = dbsn.OpenRecordset(SQLqueryn)
  rstn.Close

  SQLqueryn = "SELECT Count(*) " & _
              "  FROM KettleFinish " & _
              " WHERE KettleFinish = #" & timeStamp & #", " & _
              "   AND KettleLogic = -1 " & _
              "   AND EndOfShift = 1"
  Set rstn = dbsn.OpenRecordset(SQLqueryn)
  If Not rstn.BOF And Not rstn.EOF Then
    rstn.MoveLast
    Dim recordcount As Long
    recordcount = rstn.recordcount
  End If
  MsgBox recordcount & " records were updated as a result of the end of the shift"
  rstn.Close
  dbsn.Close

ExitSub:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
  Resume ExitSub

End Sub
```

<sup>Note: I'm used to ADO syntax, not DAO, so there might be a minor tweak or two needed, but this should get you started</sup>

This will do what your `OpenRecMassUpdate()` procedure was doing in precisely 2 SQL queries instead of that time consuming loop.

You can also do the same thing to `Sub MassIdleUpdate()`.

As a matter of fact, with a little creativity, you could probably combine the two of them into one, though keeping them separate reduces complexity, improves readability and, thus, future maintainability.

Comment: this is a much elegant approach to my solution! I will try this in my sandbox and advise the result.

Comment: Since you seem to eventually want `EndOfShift` to be 3, you could simply set that in the first place and use `KettleFinish = timeStamp` as the identifier to find the records you're after and do all the work of `MassIdleUpdate` in a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I was able to figure out a better way of updating records based on your suggestion. One more thing, would it be a better way to do the loop where I use j as a counter? I would really appreciate if you could give me your feedback about it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Freeman who guided me in the right direction. Here's my solution to the issue I had. The code has been tested in my sandbox using different scenarios and it works.

```
Public Sub OpenRecMassUpdate1()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim tempStat As String
tempStat = "Idle"
Dim stat1 As Long
stat1 = 0
Set dbsn = CurrentDb

Dim timeStamp As Date
timeStamp = Now()
SQLqueryn = "UPDATE KettleLog " & _
            "   SET KettleFinish = #" & timeStamp & "#, " & _
            "       KettleLogic = -1, " & _
            "       EndOfShift = 1 " & _
            " WHERE KettleStatus <> """ & tempStat & """" & _
            "   AND KettleLogic = 0"

dbsn.Execute SQLqueryn, dbFailOnError

SQLqueryn = "SELECT Count(*) " & _
            "AS RecCount " & _
            "  FROM KettleLog " & _
            " WHERE KettleLogic = -1 " & _
            "   AND EndOfShift = 1"

Set rstn = dbsn.OpenRecordset(SQLqueryn)

If Not rstn.BOF And Not rstn.EOF Then
Dim recordcount As Long
recordcount = rstn![RecCount]
End If

MsgBox recordcount & " records were updated as a result of the end of the shift"
rstn.Close
dbsn.Close

ExitSub:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Resume ExitSub

End Sub

Public Sub MassIdleUpdate1()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim TempKettle As String
Set dbsn = CurrentDb
SQLqueryn = "SELECT * " & _
            "  FROM KettleLog " & _
            "  WHERE EndOfShift = 1"

Set rstn = dbsn.OpenRecordset(SQLqueryn)
rstn.MoveLast
Dim rcrdcnt As Long
rcrdcnt = rstn.recordcount
ReDim machs(rcrdcnt) As String
'MsgBox rcrdcnt

rstn.MoveFirst
If Not rstn.BOF And Not rstn.EOF Then


For i = 0 To rcrdcnt - 1
machs(i) = rstn.Fields("Kettle")
rstn.MoveNext
Next
End If



SQLqueryn = "UPDATE KettleLog " & _
        " SET EndOfShift = 3 " & _
        " WHERE EndOfShift = 1 "

dbsn.Execute SQLqueryn, dbFailOnError

For j = 0 To rcrdcnt

SQLqueryn = "INSERT INTO KettleLog (Kettle, KettleStatus, WorkOrder, KettleStart, 
KettleLogic, EndOfShift) " & _
            " VALUES ( '" & machs(j) & "' , 'Idle', '0', #" & Now() & "#, '0', '2')"
MsgBox SQLqueryn
dbsn.Execute SQLqueryn, dbFailOnError

machs(j) = ""
Next
rstn.Close
dbsn.Close

ExitSub:
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description
Resume ExitSub
End Sub
```